# Displaying values from table in VS2013 forms

Tags: mysql, forms

I have created a login form, which checks database for username and password you provided, and if username exists logs you in and transfer you to next form which says: "Welcome 'username' " . Now, I want to show other info from another table about the person who loggs in that are recorded in the database. Here is my code, been struggling with it, don't know what to change to make it work, I'm getting errors for cmd and reader saying that they don't exist in the current context.

```
    private void PopulateFields()
    {
        string conString = (@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\slame\OneDrive\Dokumenti\relacijska_baza_podataka.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;");
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);

        string selectSql = "select * from Pending_Tasks";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand ("Select * From student where username='" + textBox3.Text + "' and Password ='" + textBox4.Text + "'", con);


       try
       {
           con.Open();

           using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
           {
               while(reader.Read())
            {
                textBox3.Text = (read["username"].ToString());
                textBox4.Text = (read["password"].ToString());
            }         
           } 
          }
        finally
   {
      con.Close();
}
```

Comment: I don't see any `php` here.

Comment: Any advice here? :)